# Get RelativeLayout dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

How do I get the measurements of a certain layout like linearlayout or relativelayout with its layout_width and layout_height set to wrap_content? using this method

```
 layout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
            MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
                    MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

 layout.layout(0, 0,
            layout.getMeasuredWidth(),
            layout.getMeasuredHeight());
```

returns null. I'm trying to create a bitmap image out of the relativelayout, kinda like a screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do it on the onCreate() method. Try this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus == true) {
        LinearLayout myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
        int layoutWidth = myLinearLayout.getWidth();
        int layoutHeight = myLinearLayout.getHeight();
    }
}
```

This method is called after onCreate(), when the sizes are already known.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar problem as I was trying to measure in onCreate. This thread solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight() on your view.

Remember the view has to have been layout first. You just CANNOT do it in onCreate, because the sizes are not known yet. You have to wait until it has been layout.

Comment: What if the layout is only inflated from xml?

Comment: I'm using this code to inflate `RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pointer,null);`

Answer (score 0):

public class AndroidResizeView extends Activity {

```
TextView textMyTextView;
Button myButton;

RelativeLayout rlayout;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hightk);

    rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);

    textMyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            updateSizeInfo();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    updateSizeInfo();
}

private void updateSizeInfo() {

    textMyTextView.setText(String.valueOf("Width: "
            + rlayout.getWidth() + "height ::" + rlayout.getHeight()));

}
```

}